# Como puedo almacenar un RadioButton en una base de datos

Tags: java, android, sqlite

estoy haciendo una base de datos sobre una encuesta, y dicha es de opción múltiple, pero si quiero almacenar las respuestas de opción múltiple, si el curso es un *INTEGER*, el nombre un *TEXT*, ¿qué puede ser el `RadioButton`? Gracias.

Añado esto para alguien que me ayude:

Hola, aquí tengo un error en esta línea:

```
bdEncuesta usdbh =
                    new bdEncuesta(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
```

Donde dice: `(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1);` tengo un error. Dice: `bdEncuesta() in bdEncuesta cannot be applied to.`

Esto es lo que tengo en `bdEncuesta.java`

```
 public class bdEncuesta extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE Encuestado (nombre TEXT, curso INTEGER, PREG2 text, preg3, TEXT, preg4 TEXT, preg5 TEXT)";

    public bdEncuesta(Context contexto, String nombre, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnt, int versionNva) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Encuestado");

        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Un RadioButton sería del tipo booleano (True-False). Verdadero si está marcado, falso si no lo está. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @A.Cedano los Radio Buttons tienen dos estados, marcado y no marcado,
esto lo podrías representar en Base de datos como un Booleano (true o false).

Pero en este caso si estas gastando la Base de datos SQLite de Android la [documentación oficial](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) dice:

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
>   Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Por lo que deberías almacenar los valores de si está marcado como 1 (true) y si no está marcado como 0 (false).

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Vale, gracias amigo. No me fije en eso.

Comment: @Joacer excelente... +1. No uso SQLite, no lo sabía. SQLite maneja así cómodamente (para ellos) el concepto de booleano,  dejando pendiente para el programador una tarea de control: El programador debe determinar si el RadioButton está marcado y enviar el valor `1` a la BD, y si no está marcado enviar el valor `0`. Eso hay que hacerlo, aún en BD que admitan Booleanos, pero en el caso de SQLite, **para evitar sorpresas**, habría que controlar lo que enviamos a la BD, para que la columna que funcionará "como" booleano sólo admita `0` ó `1`... :) Que no pueda recibir  un  `5`, un `8`, un `1000`

Comment: @A.Cedano excelente explicación!

Comment: Hola @PabloGonzalez si te sirvió la respuesta y es correcta te invito a que la marques como correcta, para que le pueda servir de ayuda a más gente. Saludos!